# The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdata, afnetworking-3

[image: Request image from postman[![response image from postman]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QlIS.png)I am using AFNetworking to send data to server.Below is my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dict setValue:[[arrLoginDetails objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"user_id"];

    [dict setValue:[[arrLoginDetails objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"shipper_id"];

    [dict setValue:strUuid forKey:@"imageOrderId"];

    [dict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"type"];

    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([aryImages objectAtIndex:0], 0.7);


   if([imageData length]>0){
    NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];


    if([base64String length]>0){
    [dict setValue:base64String forKey:@"file_path"];

       NSString * reqFormat= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&email=%@&dev_id=%@",UploadImage,[[arrLoginDetails objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"email"],APP_DELEGATE.stringDeviceID];

 [manager POST:reqFormat parameters:dict1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
  }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"error:%@",error.debugDescription);

 }
```

Below is the error I am getting:

The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.

**Error**:

Error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

If I nslog error.debugdescription iam getting as "The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."

Please help me to solve this error.

Thank you.

Comment: you are not getting proper JSON in response, check in postman REST api to verify.

Comment: getting response in postman..

Comment: write `manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];` before post request

Comment: @ Max same error I am getting

Comment: `manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"text/plain", nil];` to accept all type of response.

Comment: @ Max same error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

manager.requestSerializer=serializer;
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes= [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",@"application/json", nil];

 [manager POST:reqFormat parameters:dict1 progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         //Print response
     } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
         //Print error
     }];
```

In AFNetworking 3.0 `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is replaced with `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

[Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide)

Comment: Getting same error using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Comment: Use "AFHTTPSessionManager".

Comment: @user2931321 Can you Show me your error with code? Or Show me you postman request and response image.

Comment: attached images from postman in the question.Error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.} If I nslog error.debugdescription iam getting as "The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."

Comment: Can you change HTML to JSON in postman? And see it is correct or no?

Comment: it is correct. and  the response i checked in jsonlint.it is a valid json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124394/discussion-between-user2931321-and-ekta-makadiya).

Answer (score 0):

actually this problem occurred mainly two reasons

1. when your parameters are wrong. means wrong value or missing parameter.
2. check your URL . sometime it occurred cause of your wrong URL.

i faced same problem two times with same reason.